ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (cffi)
I am trying to install Selinium and this is the error that I am getting,
not sure what I m doing wrong here, I am running Windows 11 By the way I am using this on the Admin of Command Prompt< I have tried searching online for the answer but non helps me so far :(
cheers

What is the error message? Post full error message

_cffi_backend.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyErr_WriteUnraisableMsg
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313_cffi_backend.cp313-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
[end of output]

Are you using python 3.13?

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, can you edit your post with more details including the command you are running & the full output (including the error message)?

This is the command I am entering: pip install selenium

This is the command I am entering: pip install selenium
for the error please find the link below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mxf_aUctc-XGJNQCqLgOmdiLULQ32Gsl/view?usp=sharing
